# Transform an array into a comma separated variables WITHOUT apply

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to reimplement apply for practice. I figured out a naive solution to execute a function in the context of an object by temporarily decorating that function on the object and then deleting it after. But I can't figure out how to pass the fn comma separated arguments when I invoke it because they are in array form.

How can I transform an array into a comma separated variables WITHOUT apply, call, or bind?

```
function apply(fn, context, args) {
  context.fn = fn;
  var result = context.fn();
  delete context.fn;
  return result;
}

function add(a,b) {
  return a + b + this.num;
}

console.log(apply(add, {num: 10}, [3, 4])); //17
```

EDIT:

I do NOT want my values split into a string. I want my values split into [comma separated form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). This is essentially what [apply](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/) does under the hood when you pass it an array.

Comment: Use join? `join(',')` Or am I really misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Sorry, there is a miscommunication here. I do not want a string. I want my values to be separated with the comma operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: Well, you didn't say not to use `eval`, so you could use `eval` on the string produced by `join`, but that is best to avoid in general. However, your use case sounds like a special case, as you are recreating a built-in function.

Comment: @forgivenson Yes, I think you might be right. It seems like the only way to implement this is using eval(). Thanks!

Comment: nvm, I tried it and `eval` will return the result of the comma operator, so in your example it returns `4`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

`[1,2,3,4,5].join(",")`

Comment: Hey, I think I did not communicate my question correctly. I just updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in ES6 with the help of the [spread operator](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es6/#default-rest-spread):

`console.log(...myArray);`

At the time of this writing, this feature is supported by FF37 and transpilers such as [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io).

Another way of doing it would be by [currying the function](https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe) and looping to pass the arguments. Something along the lines of:

`myArray.forEach(curriedConsoleLog);`

That said, I don't see harm in just using `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

As your function can only receive two arguments this would work :

```
function apply(fn, context, args) {
  context.fn = fn;
  var result = context.fn(args[0],args[1]);
  delete context.fn;
  return result;
}

function add(a,b) {
  return a + b + this.num;
}

console.log(apply(add, {num: 10}, [3, 4]));
```

Comment: That was only an example to demonstrate expected input and output. I require a more generalized solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function apply(fn, context, args) {
    context.fn = fn;
    while (args.length) {
        context.fn = context.fn(args.shift());
    }
    return context.fn;
}

function cubus(a) {
    return function (b) {
        return function (c) {
            return a * b * c / this.num;
        }
    }
}

function add(a) {
    return function (b) {
        return a + b + this.num;
    }
}

document.write(apply(add, { num: 10 }, [3, 4]));
document.write('<br>');
document.write(apply(cubus, { num: 10 }, [3, 4, 5]));
```

have a look at [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying)